# JWT token signature

Tags: http, request, jwt, token

I am looking for a solution on how to improve security for JWT without using encrytpion and in the same time allow user a multisessions.

The standard algorithm of creating a signature is:

```
HMACSHA256( base64UrlEncode(header) + "." +  base64UrlEncode(payload), secret)
```

What if we combine some unique client identifier (IP/ MAC address/ browser Fingerprint) (smth that could be exported from the request itself without passing in request body) with our secret?

```
HMACSHA256( base64UrlEncode(header) + "." +  base64UrlEncode(payload), secret + UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
```

Such a solution will prevents the hacker to access our data even if the whole JWT will be stolen.

Unfortunately the usage of IP is not the best for UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, because the client can use dynamic IP. 
Any ideas which parameter of http request can be used as UNIQUEIDENTIFIER?

Comment: Is this only to prevent the JWT from being stolen/hijacked? Not sure about multi-sessions. I would implement rolling versioning with a UUID. Which can be used to invalidate the previous JWT after each request/authentication. Similar to how session regeneration is recommended to prevent session hi-jacking, since sessions are stored as a cookie in a similar manner as JWT. If the UUID changes from the one that was expected, force reauthentication.You would need to store the UUID someplace to validate the JWT of the current request, such as memcache or RDBM.

Comment: A similar question was asked on Security Exchange [What protects a JWT from being hijacked and used to pose as the original user?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/170599/94918)